# Total count in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I need to create a view that will display the total number of students who have declared two majors (`Major1` and `Major2` are not null).

What query should I use?

My goal is to  get a single row of output so I know `ORDER BY` clause is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Table definitions and sample data please? (Is major1 a column name?)

Comment: You have recently asked a series of extremely basic Oracle SQL questions.  Doing your homework for you is not the purpose of Stack Overflow.  Please learn to read the documentation, which is online, free and comprehensive.  [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions008.htm#SQLRF52152).

Comment: I am trying to learn, you don't have to be rude about it. It's not homework, it's exercises I am doing on my own. Sorry if I try to use online resources to learn. My bad. @apc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    CREATE VIEW GetNumberOfStudentswithMajor

    AS

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Students where Major1 is not null and Major2 is not null
```